# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation converting base64 to pdf

Tags: c#, wpf, base64

I am getting this error at this line of code:

```
this.axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(spathfile);
```

This occur after converting base64 code to pdf:

```
var base64BinaryStr = fileList.FilePath;

            byte[] lesson = Convert.FromBase64String(base64BinaryStr);

           // byte[] lesson = ReadFile(fileName);
            var spathfile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
            //move from soures to destination the extension until now is .temp
            System.IO.File.Move(spathfile,
             System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(spathfile, ".pdf"));
            //make it real pdf file  extension .pdf
            spathfile = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(spathfile, ".pdf");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(spathfile, lesson);
```

I have stepped through the code to verify if `spathfile` returns a value and there is a value in it ("C:\Users\user's Name\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpDA3B.pdf").

Comment: Are you sure the file is Base64 encoded?  If it's not you will not be able to do the conversion.  Based on the exception, I doubt the contents of this file are what you expect.

Comment: The conversion went well and I have also viewed the converted document.

Comment: Can you show the implementation around the call to `LoadFile`?  I think something might be missing here.

Comment: I am trying to read/view the pdf using a pdf reader. The point at which the error occur is immediately after the second code section. If I pass a normal path to a pdf for example saved inside mydocument it will run without error. So I am wondering while this implementation is failing.

Comment: I don't know much about axAcro, but the exception is telling you that the library cannot convert that file to PDF format for its purposes.  I would spend some time reading the documentation on the axAcro plugin to see if you need to specify a type of file encoding or something else.  And also know that simply changing a file's extension does not convert the contents of a file to something else.  It's very likely axAcro cannot open this pdf, because it is not in fact a pdf.

Comment: I tried it with axFoxitCtl and it worked. But I still want to use axAcro.

Comment: So then it's clearly an issue with decoding that file via the library you are using.  Again, read some documentation or try to save your file in something other than Base64?